Retrieve the address of a peer to peer video stream from cheap WiFi camera drone
I recently picked up a Chinese WiFi drone from which I recovered the electronic modules.
I would like to use the module allowing video transmission via Wifi for other projects. So I first tried with the official application (Bigben Fly) but it has not been maintained for a long time, so it is no longer functional on new versions of Android...
I have already looked at similar questions on the forum but they are not as precise as mine, in fact I decompiled the apk of the app with jadx and I found this code which at first glance corresponds to what I'm looking for. The app seems to use a P2P system to the address 172.16.0.1 or 172.16.0.2, which corresponds to the IP address obtained when I connect to the drone via Wifi. However using nmap I find that no ports are open on the module.
package com.yijian.auvilink.network;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import com.yijian.auvilink.bean.MyDeviceInfo;
import com.yijian.auvilink.network.g;
import com.yijian.auvilink.utils.t;
import p2ptran.sdk.p2ptransdk;

/* loaded from: /tmp/jadx-16086265272476680384.dex */
public class CameraItem implements Runnable {
    static final /* synthetic */ boolean b;
    private t A;
    private Context c;
    private String i;
    private String j;
    private String l;
    private String m;
    private int o;
    private String p;
    private Handler d = new Handler();
    private Handler e = new Handler() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.1
        @Override // android.os.Handler
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            super.handleMessage(message);
        }
    };
    private String f = null;
    private String g = null;
    private Handler h = null;
    private boolean k = false;
    private int n = 0;
    private boolean q = false;
    private boolean r = true;
    private Thread s = null;
    c a = new c(100000);
    private boolean z = false;
    private int v = 0;

    /* renamed from: u, reason: collision with root package name */
    private int f61u = 0;
    private int t = 0;
    private q w = new q();
    private n x = new n();
    private o y = new o();

    static {
        b = !CameraItem.class.desiredAssertionStatus();
    }

    public CameraItem(Context context) {
        this.o = 1;
        this.c = context;
        this.A = t.a(this.c);
        this.o = 1;
    }

    public int a() {
        return this.o;
    }

    public int b() {
        return this.n;
    }

    public String c() {
        return this.i;
    }

    public String d() {
        return this.j;
    }

    public boolean e() {
        return this.k;
    }

    public String f() {
        return this.l;
    }

    public int a(String str) {
        this.m = str;
        return 0;
    }

    public int b(String str) {
        this.p = str;
        return 0;
    }

    public String g() {
        return this.m;
    }

    public String h() {
        return this.p;
    }

    public void a(int i) {
        this.w.a(i);
        this.x.a(i);
    }

    /* JADX WARN: Multi-variable type inference failed */
    private int u() {
        int i;
        int P2PReaderGetFrame = p2ptransdk.P2PReaderGetFrame(this.v);
        if (P2PReaderGetFrame == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetUserData(P2PReaderGetFrame) == 0) {
            int P2PFrameGetLength = p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetLength(P2PReaderGetFrame);
            switch (p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetMsg(P2PReaderGetFrame)) {
                case 1:
                    p2ptransdk.P2PClientSetAddr(this.f61u, "172.16.10.1-6800");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, this.a.a, P2PFrameGetLength);
                    this.a.e();
                    switch (this.a.a()) {
                        case 1:
                            this.n = 0;
                            this.o = 1;
                            a(0, this.i, 1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            this.n = 1;
                            this.o = 1;
                            a(1, this.i, 1);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            this.n = 0;
                            this.o = 3;
                            a(0, this.i, 1);
                            com.yijian.auvilink.utils.a.a("CameraItem", "CLIENT_SYS_CONNECT=" + Integer.toString(this.n));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            this.n = 1;
                            this.o = 3;
                            a(1, this.i, 1);
                            break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, this.a.a, P2PFrameGetLength);
                    this.a.e();
                    if (this.a.a() == 2) {
                        this.n = 2;
                        a(2, this.i, 0);
                        Log.d("P2PFrameGetData", "密码错误  " + this.o + " === " + this.n);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        short b2 = this.a.b();
                        short b3 = this.a.b();
                        this.a.b();
                        this.a.b();
                        com.yijian.auvilink.utils.a.e("CameraItem", "Capability:" + ((int) b2) + "," + ((int) b3));
                        break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, this.a.a, P2PFrameGetLength);
                    this.a.e();
                    this.a.b();
                    this.a.b();
                    break;
            }
            p2ptransdk.P2PReaderFreeFrame(P2PReaderGetFrame);
            return 1;
        }
        int P2PFrameGetLength2 = p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetLength(P2PReaderGetFrame);
        int P2PFrameGetMsg = p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetMsg(P2PReaderGetFrame);
        c cVar = new c(P2PFrameGetLength2);
        switch (P2PFrameGetMsg) {
            case 2001:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                String c = cVar.c(64);
                String c2 = cVar.c(64);
                String c3 = cVar.c(64);
                int a2 = cVar.a();
                int a3 = cVar.a();
                if (P2PFrameGetLength2 < 204) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    i = cVar.a();
                }
                MyDeviceInfo.Instant().setResult(c + "", c2 + "", c3 + "", a2 + " MB", a3 + " MB", i + "%");
                this.e.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.6
                    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                    public void run() {
                        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("2000"));
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 2003:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                short b4 = cVar.b();
                int b5 = cVar.b();
                if (b5 <= 1000) {
                    String c4 = cVar.c(24);
                    g.a[] aVarArr = new g.a[b5];
                    if (b5 == 0) {
                        if (b4 == -1) {
                            this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.7
                                @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                                public void run() {
                                    de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a(com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.ad));
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.8
                                @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                                public void run() {
                                    de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a(com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.ac));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return -1;
                    }
                    com.yijian.auvilink.utils.a.a("count---result-camera", b5 + "+");
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < b5; i2++) {
                        aVarArr[i2] = new g.a();
                        aVarArr[i2].e = new int[4];
                        aVarArr[i2].e[0] = cVar.a();
                        aVarArr[i2].e[1] = cVar.a();
                        aVarArr[i2].e[2] = cVar.a();
                        aVarArr[i2].e[3] = cVar.a();
                        int a4 = cVar.a();
                        int a5 = cVar.a();
                        int a6 = cVar.a();
                        int a7 = cVar.a();
                        int a8 = cVar.a();
                        int[] iArr = new int[7];
                        p2ptransdk.HL2Time(a4, a5, iArr);
                        aVarArr[i2].b = new g.b(iArr);
                        p2ptransdk.HL2Time(a6, a7, iArr);
                        aVarArr[i2].c = new g.b(iArr);
                        aVarArr[i2].d = a8;
                        aVarArr[i2].a = aVarArr[i2].b.a + "-" + aVarArr[i2].b.b + "-" + aVarArr[i2].b.c + " " + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", Integer.valueOf(aVarArr[i2].b.d), Integer.valueOf(aVarArr[i2].b.e), Integer.valueOf(aVarArr[i2].b.f));
                    }
                    g.a().a(c4, b4, b5, aVarArr);
                    this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.9
                        @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                        public void run() {
                            de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("com.auvilink.getreplay.success"));
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2019:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                int a9 = cVar.a();
                if (a9 != -1) {
                    c(1001, a9);
                    this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.12
                        @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                        public void run() {
                            de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("2019"));
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2021:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                int a10 = cVar.a();
                if (a10 != -1) {
                    c(1002, a10);
                    this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.13
                        @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                        public void run() {
                            de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("2021"));
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2023:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                final int a11 = cVar.a();
                this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.2
                    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                    public void run() {
                        com.yijian.auvilink.a.a aVar = new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("2023");
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("resule", a11);
                        aVar.a(bundle);
                        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(aVar);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 2025:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                cVar.b();
                final byte c5 = cVar.c();
                cVar.c();
                c(1001, -1);
                this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.4
                    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                    public void run() {
                        com.yijian.auvilink.a.a aVar = new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("2019");
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("mode", c5);
                        aVar.a(bundle);
                        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(aVar);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 2027:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                if (cVar.a() != -1) {
                    this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.3
                        @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                        public void run() {
                            de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("1006"));
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2047:
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                final int a12 = cVar.a();
                this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.5
                    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                    public void run() {
                        com.yijian.auvilink.a.a aVar = new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("2047");
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("resule", a12);
                        aVar.a(bundle);
                        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(aVar);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.K /* 20017 */:
                this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.11
                    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                    public void run() {
                        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("20017"));
                    }
                });
                break;
            case com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.M /* 20019 */:
                com.yijian.auvilink.a.a aVar = new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("20019");
                p2ptransdk.P2PFrameGetData(P2PReaderGetFrame, cVar.a, P2PFrameGetLength2);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putByte("state", cVar.a[0]);
                aVar.a(bundle);
                de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(aVar);
                break;
            case com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.G /* 20023 */:
                this.d.post(new Runnable() { // from class: com.yijian.auvilink.network.CameraItem.10
                    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                    public void run() {
                        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a("20023"));
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
        p2ptransdk.P2PReaderFreeFrame(P2PReaderGetFrame);
        return 1;
    }

    private void c(int i, int i2) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = i;
        message.obj = Integer.valueOf(i2);
        this.h.sendMessage(message);
    }

    /* loaded from: /tmp/jadx-16086265272476680384.dex */
    public class a {
        public String a;
        public int b;

        public a() {
        }
    }

    public void a(int i, String str, int i2) {
        a aVar = new a();
        aVar.a = str;
        aVar.b = i2;
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = i;
        message.obj = aVar;
        this.h.sendMessage(message);
    }

    /* loaded from: /tmp/jadx-16086265272476680384.dex */
    public class b {
        public String a = new String();
        public String b = new String();
        public String c = new String();

        public b() {
        }
    }

    public void a(int i, String str, String str2, String str3) {
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        while (!this.r) {
            try {
                if (u() <= 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(10L);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        this.q = false;
    }

    public int a(String str, String str2, String str3, Handler handler, String str4, boolean z, String str5) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            this.h = handler;
            this.i = str;
            this.m = str2;
            this.p = str3;
            this.j = str4;
            this.k = z;
            this.l = str5;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void i() {
        this.v = p2ptransdk.P2PCreateReader();
        this.f61u = p2ptransdk.P2PCreateClient(this.v, 100, 100, 3600000, 0);
        this.t = p2ptransdk.P2PCreateSearchSession(this.v, this.i);
        p2ptransdk.P2PClientLogin(this.f61u, "112.74.197.198-6000", this.i, "admin", this.p);
        this.w.a();
        this.x.a();
        this.q = true;
        this.r = false;
        this.s = new Thread(this);
        this.s.start();
    }

    private void a(int i, int i2, String str) {
        com.yijian.auvilink.a.a aVar = new com.yijian.auvilink.a.a(com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.af);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("onlineNums", i);
        bundle.putInt("maxNums", i2);
        bundle.putString("deviceId", str);
        aVar.a(bundle);
        de.greenrobot.event.c.a().d(aVar);
    }

    public void j() {
    }

    public int k() {
        if (this.f61u != 0) {
            this.r = true;
            try {
                this.s.join();
                while (this.q) {
                    Thread.sleep(1L);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            if (!b && this.f61u == 0) {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
            this.w.b();
            this.x.b();
            p2ptransdk.P2PClientLogout(this.f61u);
            p2ptransdk.P2PDeleteObject(this.t);
            p2ptransdk.P2PDeleteObject(this.f61u);
            p2ptransdk.P2PDeleteObject(this.v);
            this.z = true;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public int a(String str, String str2) {
        this.f = str;
        this.g = str2;
        return 0;
    }

    /* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public String l() {
        return this.f;
    }

    /* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public String m() {
        return this.g;
    }

    public int n() {
        if (this.f61u != 0) {
            p2ptransdk.P2PClientReconnect(this.f61u, 10000, 10000);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int a(int i, int i2, int i3, h hVar) {
        if (this.f61u == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.w.a(this.f61u, i, i2, i3, hVar);
    }

    public int a(int i, int i2) {
        return this.w.c();
    }

    public int a(int i, int i2, int i3) {
        return this.y.a(this.f61u, i, i2, i3);
    }

    public int o() {
        return this.y.a();
    }

    public int b(int i, int i2, int i3, h hVar) {
        this.x.a(this.f61u, i, i2, i3, hVar);
        return 0;
    }

    public int b(int i, int i2) {
        this.x.c();
        return 0;
    }

    public void p() {
        this.w.e();
    }

    public void q() {
        this.w.d();
    }

    public int a(int i, int i2, byte[] bArr, int i3) {
        if (this.f61u == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        p2ptransdk.P2PClientSend(this.f61u, i, i2, bArr, i3);
        return 0;
    }

    /* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public int a(int[] iArr, int i, int i2) {
        d dVar = new d(64);
        if (iArr == null) {
            dVar.a(0);
            dVar.a(0);
            dVar.a(0);
            dVar.a(0);
        } else {
            dVar.a(iArr[0]);
            dVar.a(iArr[1]);
            dVar.a(iArr[2]);
            dVar.a(iArr[3]);
        }
        dVar.a(i);
        dVar.a(i2);
        a(com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.x, 100, dVar.a, dVar.b);
        return 0;
    }

    /* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public int r() {
        a(com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.z, 100, (byte[]) null, 0);
        return 0;
    }

    /* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public int s() {
        a(com.yijian.auvilink.mainapp.a.B, 100, (byte[]) null, 0);
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean t() {
        return this.z;
    }
}

So I hope that some people here are familiar with this type of communication protocol and could guide me to successfully obtain the video stream in the same way as the application.
